# AD user provisioning: domain-field

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, provisioning

I'm creating a VBS to create a user from our HR-systems.
Most of it worked; but I noticed the domain field stays blank *(the field on the right of the logon name in the `dsa.msc` tool; the second part of the User Principal Name)*. 
you can see it in [this screenshot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb742516.kerb02_big%28l=en-us%29.gif) as "@Entcert2.com"

I can't find any information on this on the internet.
There is basically only one value possible, but it's blank after the user creation.
The NETBIOS-domain name is filled in correctly.

What's the correct fieldname for this to fill in the value using vbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forget to fill the [userPrincipalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: embarassing answer: I had the userPrincipalName but without the domain.

Comment: correct: I first wrote `objNewUser.Put "userPrincipalName", gebruikersnaam`  It should have been `objNewUser.Put "userPrincipalName", gebruikersnaam & "@testdomain.local"`